# How to fill an InfoPath (used to populate a SharePoint list) form automatically with data in excel?

Tags: infopath, excel

My SharePoint hosts a list (with certain columns, say A, B, C, D)in which new line items are added with a form built with InfoPath (which has corresponding fields A, B, C, D). It becomes a tedious task when there are hundreds of lines of data, as I have to fill them in manually one after the another in the form. Is there any way, in which if I organise all the data that I'm trying to store in my SharePoint list in an excel sheet, it will be possible to automatically upload them on to the list?